# What type face is used for Wexford Plantation's logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo

I would like to identify the font in this image to add more text.

[image: Text within a border "Wexford / W / PLANTATION"]

Answer (score 2):

'Wexford' and 'Plantation' are two different fonts for sure.

The font for 'Wexford' is called "Patrick":

[image: Patrick Font]

The 'PLANTATION' text is a low enough resolution that you could get away with using any of the common serif fonts without anyone noticing any difference